# Find redundant user functions

Tags: php, function, redundancy

I'm profiling an app that has a boat load of functions in many files and I'm trying to isolate functions that don't get called ever.

Any ideas before I proceed?

Comment: Looking for redundant (twice-or-more-defined) is different than looking for unused (defined but never called) ones.  Which are you actually trying to do?

Comment: 'twice-or-more-defined' would cause an error. I'm looking for 'defined but never called'.

Comment: @Peter Bailey: Redundant can also mean 'excess', not just 'duplicate'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is an easy way to do this. `print_r(get_defined_functions());` in a file that can be included at the end of every file or in a global. Collect the output and do searches on all your files for function calls. This will isolate out your functions.

Or

Move all the functions to an include file, comment out the functions and then allow the application to error. As you get errors for those functions un-comment the functions to resolve the errors. At the end of all your checks you'll have a list of commented functions that aren't utilized.

Either way it's not easy.

Comment: Thanks for the get_defined_functions() tip. Looks like your first method could be it.